# Haskell System.Directory.doesFileExist and non-ASCII paths

Tags: haskell, unicode, filesystems, ghc

```
import System.Directory
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS  
import qualified Data.ByteString.UTF8 as BS_UTF8

main = do
    putStrLn "Input path to some file: "
    raw_inputed_path <- BS.getLine
    let inputed_path = BS_UTF8.toString raw_inputed_path
    such_file_exists <- doesFileExist inputed_path
    such_directory_exists <- doesDirectoryExist inputed_path
    if such_file_exists 
        then putStrLn "Yeah, I see it!"
        else if such_directory_exists
            then putStrLn "Aha, I see it, but it's a directory!"
            else putStrLn "Hmm... No such..."
```

This code perfectly works with ASCII-paths only. But if I use paths with non-ASCII symbols, `doesFileExist` and `doesDirectoryExist` always return `False`. Why?

- Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 x86_64
- ghc 6.12.1

Comment: See: [GHC #3307 (System.IO and System.Directory functions not Unicode-aware under  Unix)](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3307). If I'm reading it correctly, it has been fixed since GHC 7.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to GHC 7.x series - 6.12 is now nearly 3 years out of date. The behavior was fixed around a year ago.

Comment: Thank you! Upgrade to 7.4.1 - and now this code works perfectly, even without ByteString.